# SDL_GetDesktopDisplayMode() unable to get 1080

Tags: c++, sdl-2, screen-resolution

```
//Get screen resolution
    SDL_DisplayMode current;
        cout << "num_displays : " << SDL_GetNumVideoDisplays() << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < SDL_GetNumVideoDisplays(); ++i){
            SDL_GetDesktopDisplayMode(i, &current);
            cout << "current.w [ " << current.w << " ] - current.h [ " << current.h << " ]\n";
        }
```

The following code prints out the screen resolution of each display attached. Problem is that when I run it on 1920 x 1080 mode, it shows me a wrong resolution. However if I lower down my resolution to 1600 x 900 or lower on my main display, the value of current.w & current.h is perfect.

Is this an SDL limitation or are my display drivers faulty?

IDE : CodeBlocks(32 bit) - Compiler: MinGW

EDIT : Wrong is actually a very specific value and not garbage.
Instead of 1920 - 1080, wrong output is ALWAYS  1536 - 864

Comment: What does "wrong" actually mean (half what it should be, negative, NaN, ...)?

Comment: The factor is 1.25  did you (or your OS) set your desktop (highdpi) scaling to 1.25 on this resolution? If that's the case you might want to set your application to highdpi aware, however that is done on your OS (plist on osx or manifest on windows).

Answer (score 3):

Turns out @PeterT was right. I'm using windows 10 and scaling was 125%. Reducing the scaling to 100% resolved the problem. 
When I lowered my resolution, it turns out Windows automatically changed my scaling to 100%.

Comment: if you're just worrying about windows then I think the window flag [`SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WindowFlags) might be enough to allow you to render at a native resolution.